# Objective-C Category Question

Tags: objective-c, sorting, objective-c-category

I've created a custom sorting by creating a new category for the `NSString` class. Below is my code.

```
@implementation NSString (Support)

- (NSComparisonResult)sortByPoint:(NSString *)otherString {
  int first = [self calculateWordValue:self];
  int second = [self calculateWordValue:otherString];

  if (first > second) {
    return NSOrderedAscending;
  }

  else if (first < second) {
    return NSOrderedDescending;
  }

  return NSOrderedSame;
}

- (int)calculateWordValue:(NSString *)word {
  int totalValue = 0;
  NSString *pointPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pointvalues"ofType:@"plist"];
  NSDictionary *pointDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pointPath];

  for (int index = 0; index < [word length]; index++) {
    char currentChar = [word characterAtIndex:index];
    NSString *individual = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%c",currentChar];
    individual = [individual uppercaseString];
    NSArray *numbersForKey = [pointDictionary objectForKey:individual];
    NSNumber *num = [numbersForKey objectAtIndex:0];
    totalValue += [num intValue];

    // cleanup
    individual = nil;
    numbersForKey = nil;
    num = nil;
  }

  return totalValue;
}

@end
```

My question is whether I create a point dictionary to determine the point value associated with each character in the alphabet based on a plist. Then in my view controller, I call

```
NSArray *sorted = [words sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(sortByPoint:)];
```

to sort my table of words by their point values. However, creating a new dictionary each time the `-sortByPoint:` method is called is extremely inefficient. Is there a way to create the pointDictionary beforehand and use it for each subsequent call in the `-calculateWordValue:`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for the static keyword. If you do this:

```
static NSDictionary *pointDictionary = nil
if (pointDictionary==nil) {
    NSString *pointPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pointvalues" ofType:@"plist"];
    pointDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pointPath];
}
```

`pointDictionary` will be persistent for the lifetime of your app.

One other optimization is to build a cache of scores by using this against each of your words:

```
[dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[word calculateWordValue:word]] forKey:word];
```

Then use the `keysSortedByValueUsingSelector:` method to extract your list of words (note the selector chould be compare:, since the objects being compared are the NSNumbers).

Finally, the word argument on your method is redundant. Use self instead:

```
-(int)calculateWordValue {
    ...

    for (int index = 0; index < [self length]; index++)
    {
        char currentChar = [self characterAtIndex:index];
        ...
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I need the word argument for the other NSString that's passed into the (NSComparisonResult) sortByPoint: ?

Comment: No, you can just call [otherString calculateWordValue] to get its score.

Comment: aahrens: this is a better answer than mine. It's easier to implement and comes with bonus optimizations. I think Graham deserves the best answer flag here.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `sortByPoint:(NSString *) otherString` method to take the dictionary as a parameter, and pass it your pre-created dictionary.

`sortByPoint:(NSString *)otherString withDictionary:(NSDictionary *)pointDictionary`

EDIT: Won't work because of usage in sortedArrayWithSelector. Apologies. Instead, you may be better off creating a wrapper class for your point dictionary as a singleton which you then obtain a reference to each time your sort function runs.

In `calculateWordValue`:

```
NSDictionary *pointDictionary = [[DictWrapper sharedInstance] dictionary];
```

`DictWrapper` has an NSDictionary as a property, and a class method `sharedInstance` (to return the singleton. You have to set that dictionary and pre-initialize it before you do you first sorting.

Comment: How would it look like then in the @selector argument in the words sortedArrayusingSelector@selector ?

Comment: Excellent question. I answered in haste, but I am thinking about that now!